# Compare a string length after 1 second with same string

Tags: java, javafx

Currently, my application shows who's typing when the following event occurs:

```
textfield.setOnKeyPressed((keyEvent) -> {                
    if(keyEvent.getCode().isDigitKey() || keyEvent.getCode().isLetterKey() ||
        keyEvent.getCode().isModifierKey() || keyEvent.getCode().isWhitespaceKey() ||
        keyEvent.isShiftDown()){
            whoTypes();
}
```

But I want that when the user is not typing or stops typing, it should show nothing.

I want that after 1 second, it should verify if the textfield is the same length as it was before. If it is the same length, the screen will show that the user has stopped writing. If the length is different from the one before that second, it will keep showing that the user is typing.

Comment: Define "stopped". 1 second? 100 milliseconds? You're going to need to decide on this first and likely need to use a timer of some sort that is de-activeated and re-activated after each keypress.

Comment: You'll need a callback on timer, not a callback on keypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you don't really want to test for key presses; you want to know if the text changed. For example, the user might use the mouse to copy and paste into the text field. So you should register your listener with the `textProperty()` of the text field, instead of using a key event listener.

You can do something like this:

```
PauseTransition timer = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
    timer.playFromStart());
timer.setOnFinished(e -> System.out.println("Text field idle for one second"));
```

Comment: That worked just perfectly, damn man. You're awesome, thank you very much!!!! If I could, I would rate you 1000000 times.